# Docker using Rancher throwing an error and Gradle looking for jdk at an older JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, docker, gradle, rancher, netflix-conductor

I am new to docker and I was trying to run Netflix conductor on my local machine from [here](https://github.com/Netflix/conductor) using rancher and docker cli. I cloned the repository, went inside the docker directory and ran
`docker-compose up`

This is the output I got

```
PS C:\Users\X\Conductor_impl\conductor\docker> docker-compose up
[+] Running 2/2
 ! conductor-ui Warning                                                                                                       15.1s 
 ! conductor-server Warning                                                                                                   15.2s 
2023/08/02 12:18:52 http2: server: error reading preface from client //./pipe/docker_engine: file has already been closed
[+] Building 6.5s (10/15)
 => [conductor-server internal] load .dockerignore                                                                             0.0s
 => => transferring context: 117B                                                                                              0.0s 
 => [conductor-server internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                          0.0s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.50kB                                                                                         0.0s 
 => [conductor-server internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/eclipse-temurin:11-jre-jammy                               5.1s
 => [conductor-server internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/eclipse-temurin:11-jdk-jammy                               5.1s 
 => [conductor-server internal] load build context                                                                             1.0s
 => => transferring context: 295.93kB                                                                                          1.0s 
 => CANCELED [conductor-server stage-1 1/6] FROM docker.io/library/eclipse-temurin:11-jre-jammy@sha256:ffb4e17eb2884d94bfc8ba  1.9s 
 => => resolve docker.io/library/eclipse-temurin:11-jre-jammy@sha256:ffb4e17eb2884d94bfc8bac5b5e4321fef652851b5eb5ec8e4a2dd2d  0.0s 
 => => sha256:2c8a391f1a44886d7674d4c6604f674f1a639f84b5c1681b03826ac4021766f1 0B / 46.87MB                                    1.3s 
 => => sha256:dd008fd673e62dbc2983fea0bbb3c1537c7bd0a29c81811bd4b5d7e88ba5c8de 0B / 159B                                       1.3s
 => => sha256:ffb4e17eb2884d94bfc8bac5b5e4321fef652851b5eb5ec8e4a2dd2dbd2a7651 1.21kB / 1.21kB                                 0.0s 
 => => sha256:894577b0e822baf934c52d659f625565afa762d9f0df182495b1259164b7917f 1.16kB / 1.16kB                                 0.0s 
 => => sha256:869eee3db00a3cf41f5851544d8fc67e11e55ce84801d10d346acf16f3e67571 6.39kB / 6.39kB                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [conductor-server builder 1/4] FROM docker.io/library/eclipse-temurin:11-jdk-jammy@sha256:e793d592c394150ce7da5e83  0.0s 
 => [conductor-server builder 2/4] COPY . /conductor                                                                           0.6s 
 => [conductor-server builder 3/4] WORKDIR /conductor                                                                          0.0s 
 => ERROR [conductor-server builder 4/4] RUN ./gradlew build -x test --stacktrace                                              0.3s 
------
 > [conductor-server builder 4/4] RUN ./gradlew build -x test --stacktrace:
0.299 /bin/sh: 1: ./gradlew: not found
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c ./gradlew build -x test --stacktrace" did not complete successfully: exit code: 127
```

I thought of manually adding the gradle wrapper and then it is showing me that the JAVA_HOME is not configured properly.

I used the maven wrapper command after pasting the same settings.gradle file from the parent directory to use ./gradlew .

```
PS C:\Users\X\Conductor_impl\conductor> ./gradlew build -x test --stacktrace

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. Tried location: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.2.1\bin\java.exe

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.internal.jvm.JavaHomeException: The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. Tried location: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.2.1\bin\java.exe
        at org.gradle.internal.jvm.Jvm.findExecutable(Jvm.java:183)
```

Gradle thinks im using jdk18 when I am using JDK11.

```
C:\Users\X>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11
```

Can someone help me fix gradle thinking im using jdk18(also tell me if my approach is wrong). Also, doesn't a docker file not need anything to be set up externally??